# Document ready after window.location change in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm using `window.location.replace()` to redirect to a new page (same domain as the original). However, I need to run some jquery code after the redirection has finished. I can't simply embed the code I want to run on the target page, since it needs data I have on the current context.

Is there a way of setting a trigger similar to document.ready but on the new page?

My first idea was

```
window.location.replace(data.redirect);
$(document).ready(
  function() {
   (use data variable from outer context)
  }
);
```

But this won't work as the function will be run on the current document.

Is this even possible?

Comment: No there isn't.  Once you have left the page your javascript variables are gone.

Comment: One clarification: I COULD embed code on the page data.redirect, but still I need to pass data to that page.

Comment: @JamesMontagne I see, I was afraid that was the case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, not possible, but if you're on the same domain, have you considered putting that information in a cookie?

Answer (score 4):

You should append a #datayouneed to the URL, and read the hash portion of the URL via the javascript on the new page.

Comment: While it's an option, I'm not sure it answer his question.

Comment: Yes, I think this or @chrismarx 's answer are the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot get your code onto the target page, you cannot execute your code on the target page. There are a few ways for you to get your data over there though:

1. Post to the new page
2. Carry it over via the query string
3. Load it into a cookie
4. Store it in a session variable

Other than these few methods, you won't have many other options for getting your data from A to B. The last two options really are only possible if the user stays on your domain/server.

Answer (score 0):

You can set has on your current url and you can read it on second page .

In first page ;

```
window.location.href = "http://second.page#param1=val1&param2=val2"
```

In second page you can use ;

```
if(window.location.hash) {//Something like param1=val1&param2=val2
  //Do your action
} else {
  // Another action
}
```

You can refer [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp) for more information about hash